# UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode

I have UITableView and I made implementation for `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        NSUInteger beforeDeleteCount = historyArray.count;

        VideoItem *video = [historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[HistoryRepository sharedHistory] removeFromHistories:video];

        if (self.titleSort) {
            [self sortArrayByTitleAtoZWithReloadData:NO];
        } else {
            [self sortArrayByNormalWithReloadData:NO];
        }

        NSUInteger afterDeleteCount = historyArray.count;

        if (beforeDeleteCount == afterDeleteCount) {
            [table reloadData];
        } else {
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        }
    }
}

-(void)sortArrayByNormalWithReloadData:(BOOL)reload {
    self.titleSort = NO;

    historyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[HistoryRepository sharedHistory] historyArray]];

    if (reload) {
        [self setTableHeader];
        [table reloadData];
    }
}

-(void)sortArrayByTitleAtoZWithReloadData:(BOOL)reload {

    self.titleSort = YES;

    NSSortDescriptor * sortDescriptor = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)] autorelease];

    historyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[[[HistoryRepository sharedHistory] historyArray] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]]];

    if (reload) {
        [self setTableHeader];
        [table reloadData];
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [historyArray count];
}
```

And I still get this kind of error all the time:

```
Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0. The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (27) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (27), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).
```

I always making a check if it's the same count so reload the table and don't delete but still i'm getting this error.

Comment: You base your counts on historyArray but you remove from [HistoryRepository sharedHistory]. How do these two relate to each other? How do you synchronise them? Can you show the rest od the code, especially implementation od „tableView:numberOfRows:inSection”?

Comment: @Losiowaty I just update the question with the relevant code, you can see i set `historyArray` inside these methods: `sortArrayByNormalWithReloadData` and `sortArrayByTitleAtoZWithReloadData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reordering the data source array after **deleting** an item makes no sense if the array is already sorted.

And you **must not** call `deleteRowsAtIndexPaths` after reordering the data source array anyway.

This version of `commitEditingStyle:` is sufficient

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        VideoItem *video = [historyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [[HistoryRepository sharedHistory] removeFromHistories:video];
        [historyArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
}
```